# Birationally equivalent elliptic curves and singularities

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves, integration, birational-geometry, resolution-of-singularities

I got the following cubic elliptic curve from some physical problem $$E_c(\mathbb{C}): w^2=4 z^3-zG_2-G_3,$$ where $G_2=3
   \alpha ^2+\gamma$ and $G_3=\alpha ^3-\alpha  \gamma
   -\beta ^2$ for known real parameters $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$. In fact, $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$ are such that the roots of $E_c(\mathbb{C})$ are real.

Under the birational change of variables $$  x\to \frac{w-\beta }{2
   (z-\alpha )} \quad \text{and} \quad y\to \frac{(w-\beta )^2}{4
   (z-\alpha )^2}-2 z-\alpha $$
with inverse
$$ z\to \frac{1}{2}(x^2-y-\alpha) \quad \text{and} \quad w\to x^3-xy-3x\alpha+\beta
  ,$$
we get a quartic curve $$E_q(\mathbb{C}): y^2=x^4-6 \alpha x^2+4
   \beta  x+\gamma.$$

I am interested in writing the integral $$\xi(z):=\int_\infty^z \frac{dz}{w},$$
defined on $E_c(\mathbb{C})$ in terms of the variables on $E_q(\mathbb{C})$. Using the above birational map and working out the Jacobian, I find $$\int_\infty^{z(x)} \frac{dz}{w}=\int_\infty^{x(z)=\frac{w(z)-\beta }{2
   (z-\alpha )}}\frac{dx}{y}.$$
I tested this relation using `NIntegrate[]` in Mathematica and it seems the two integrals agree to arbitrary precision far from $z=\alpha$. However, for $z\sim \alpha$, the LHS integral gives a finite number (up to periods) and the RHS integral gives zero (up to periods). I could have expected this difference, since $z=\alpha$ gives $x=\infty$.

**I am wondering about what I could do to 'regulate' or 'blow up' this singularity locally and make the above two expressions equal globally.** The point $z=\alpha$ is of physical relevance in my problem so understanding its image onto $E_q(\mathbb{C})$ is important. Any suggestion?

Also, is my problem related to the so-called '[points at infinity](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/188871/why-there-are-two-point-at-infinity-on-certain-elliptic-curve)'? I am asking because one of the comment by Michael Stoll says "*The "points at infinity" then are the points one has to add to the affine curve to obtain the smooth projective model.*" This seems to resonate with my problem here.

Comment: Are you sure that you don't just have really bad numerical behavior when $z$ is close to $\alpha$?

Comment: Yes, it could be related to the fact that the quartic curve has two points (or rather, places) at infinity, namely $y \sim x^2$ and $y \sim -x^2$. So in your second integral, which one of these two points is meant? Could it be that you are computing the integral from one point to the other?